# Protractor - headless execution for parallel test is failing

Tags: protractor, headless

Trying to run two instances of webdriver with headless chrome browser.
Getting below error when ran with protractor-beautiful-reporter

**I/runnerCli - ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'Results/Jsons/000000d8-003c-0046-00f3-00a30045006c.json'**

**conf.js**

```
let HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    directConnect: true,
    allScriptsTimeout: 900000,
    getPageTimeout: 120000,

    onPrepare: function () {

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            filename: 'MVP.html',
            baseDirectory: 'Results',
            preserveDirectory: false,
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            screenshotsSubfolder: 'Screenshots',
            jsonsSubfolder: 'Jsons',
            docTitle: 'PM UI Test Result',
            sortFunction: function sortFunction(a, b) {
                if (a.instanceId < b.instanceId) return -1;
                else if (a.instanceId > b.instanceId) return 1;

                if (a.timestamp < b.timestamp) return -1;
                else if (a.timestamp > b.timestamp) return 1;

                return 0;
            },
            clientDefaults: {
                showTotalDurationIn: 'belowHeader',
                totalDurationFormat: 'hms'
            }
        }).getJasmine2Reporter());
    },

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ["--headless", "--window-size=1920,1200"]
        },
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        trustAllSSLCertificates: true,
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS: true,
        maxInstances: 2,
        shardTestFiles: true
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 900000,
    },

    specs: ['../tests/abc.js',
            '../tests/xyz.js'
    ],
};
```

Comment: Does it pass when running headlessly and `maxInstances` = 1?

Comment: @DublinDev yes it passes when maxInstances = 1.